# Cannot post to Sinatra but get works

Tags: ruby, post, sinatra

I am writing an app that runs Sinatra as a background thread to provide an API.

I defined a route for a GET that works ok but when I try  post I keep seeing it fail in WEBrick at the same place. The error is:

```
[2018-01-18 20:43:05] ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
/Users/atkinsb/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:90:in `service'
/Users/atkinsb/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
/Users/atkinsb/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
/Users/atkinsb/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/server.rb:290:in `block in start_thread'
::1 - - [18/Jan/2018:20:43:05 GMT] "POST /message HTTP/1.1" 500 320
- -> /message
```

I think the problem is on line 86:

```
status, headers, body = @app.call(env)
```

This always returns nil for all three variables when I do the post.

```
post '/message' do
  ApiServer::Base::SM.message(JSON.parse(request.body.read))
end
```

The post body:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "sender": "localhost",
  "action": "SYS_NORMAL_SHUTDOWN",
  "payload": "",
  "ack": "0",
  "date_time": "2018-01-18 08:58:50 +0000"
}
```

I'm posting with a header in postman:

```
Content-Type application/json
```

I'm stumped by this. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

PS. I forgot to mention that the json body is parsed ok in the route...

Also the body returned from the post is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Internal Server Error</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <H1>Internal Server Error</H1>
           undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
        <HR>
        <ADDRESS>
           WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.4.2/2017-09-14) at
           localhost:4567
        </ADDRESS>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, after all that. It seems that the problem was I needed to return some sort of response.

```
  # Server API route '/message'
  def message(params)
      js = build_message(params['action'], params['payload'])
      write_message_to_file(js)
      '{ "status": "Message Received" }'
  end
```

Comment: I'd suggest you use `halt` with a status too, a 201 or 202 (they're unloved but useful codes:), e.g. `halt 202, '{ "status": "Message Received" }'`. Not only will it avoid errors like the one you found it also makes clear what you expect returned and that you don't expect a page returned for rendering. `:provides => :json` as a route condition helps with clarity by populating the Accepts header too.